# Last n-th day before today

Tags: php, date

Given just an integer between 1 and 31, how can I get "last n-th day date" (meaning last is in the past)? I'm looking for an equivalent of `strtotime("last Monday")` but for day of month - something like `strtotime("last 26th")`.

For example if we assume that today is 2018-06-04:

- If my number is 3 then 2018-06-03 should be returned
- If my number is 4 then 2018-06-04 should be returned
- If my number is 5 then 2018-05-05(5th day of last month) should be returned

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
if(intval(date("d"))>=$day)
echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime("first day of this month +$day days"));
else
echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime("first day of last month +$day days"));
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read the help pages, especially the sections named "What topics can I ask about here?" and "What types of questions should I avoid asking?". Also please take the tour and read about how to ask good questions. Lastly please learn how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// we care about today
$d = date('d') ;

// the date you are checking for
$theDate = 3 ; // you will set this to whatever you want

// format the date 
$useDate = (intval($theDate) < 10) ? '0' . $theDate : $theDate ;

// is it greater than today?
if (intval($theDate) > $d) {
    // you want the previous month
    $month = 'previous month' ;
} else {
   // you want this month
    $month = 'this month' ;
}

$result = date('Y-m-',strtotime($month)) . $useDate ;
```